# Processing messages through named:channels with prefetch >= 1

Tags: spring-xd

Good evening everybody

I run with SpringXD-1.3.0.RELEASE (configuration: 3 admin and 3 container) and RabbitMQ 3.5.7 (3 nodes) into following scenario:

```
stream create --name fire  --definition "time --timeUnit=MILLISECONDS  > topic:fire" --deploy
stream create --name fireeater_1  --definition "topic:fire > null"
stream create --name fireeater_2  --definition "topic:fire > null"
stream create --name fireeater_3  --definition "topic:fire > null"
stream create --name fireeater_4  --definition "topic:fire > null"
job create test123 --definition "timestampfile --directory=/tmp"

stream deploy fireeater_1 --properties "module.null.consumer.durableSubscription=true,module.null.count=0,module.null.consumer.prefetch=500"
stream deploy fireeater_2 --properties "module.null.consumer.durableSubscription=true,module.null.count=0,module.null.consumer.prefetch=500"
stream deploy fireeater_3 --properties "module.null.consumer.durableSubscription=true,module.null.count=0,module.null.consumer.prefetch=500"
stream deploy fireeater_4 --properties "module.null.consumer.durableSubscription=true,module.null.count=0,module.null.consumer.prefetch=500"

job deploy test123
```

After few minutes this exception is thrown on one container.

```
2016-01-13T18:08:47+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.job:test123-6 listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:721) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:711) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:569) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 6
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.getChannel(ChannelManager.java:80) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:552) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

At the end the container processes the messages from rabbitmq very slowly. Only an undeployment of the "fire"-stream or a container restart will help.

It seems so that a message channel, used by the job is closed by the stream.

-- Update --
Today I saw more output from the log and it seems so that the channel is closed by the message bus itself. Here the log for the exception

```
2016-02-23T15:05:18+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection 10.0.3.210:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
2016-02-23T15:05:18+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2 listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:865) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1352) [spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1096) [spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1080) [spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1197) [spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@69022500]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(RabbitMessageBus.java:891) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
... 10 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:67) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:51) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:833) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.access$400(CachingConnectionFactory.java:822) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:474) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:450) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:419) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:412) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1200(CachingConnectionFactory.java:86) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:838) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createChannel(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:139) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1278) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1271) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:619) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:717) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:329) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:321) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:125) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:143) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:503) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:44) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 3289
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.getChannel(ChannelManager.java:82) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar!/:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:556) ~[na:na]
... 1 common frames omitted

 2016-02-23T15:05:18+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection 10.0.3.210:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
 2016-02-23T15:05:18+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.test123-6 listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
 com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
at      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:739) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:729) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:573) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
 Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 3289
at  com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.getChannel(ChannelManager.java:82) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at  com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:556) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
... 1 common frames omitted

2016-02-23T15:05:18+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.fireeater_1-1 listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:739) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:729) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:573) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
 Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 3289
at   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.getChannel(ChannelManager.java:82) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
at   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:556) ~[amqp-client-3.5.2.jar:na]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

Does someone know why the exception is thrown and how is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: I've had it running on my laptop (singlenode) for an hour now, without any problems. I can't think of anything that would cause a channel to become invalidated. Is there anything else of interest in the log? Can you reproduce with DEBUG logging? Is there anything of interest in the RabbitMQ log?

Comment: Hi I ran today the scenario with debug logging. I don't have much more infos than yesterday, but i saw more on the log. The channel is not invalidated by the stream but by the message bus. I updated the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "closed by the messagebus itself". The smoking gun is `Unknown channel number 3289 at ... getChannel()` on a send. Since everyone's sharing the same connection, this is a fatal error on the connection and it is closed so everyone gets a shutdown signal - but everything should recover ok. That channel number (3289) is rather large. Do you have anything else running in that container? What does the channels page in the admin UI look like? I wonder if increasing the channel cache will help (XD doesn't expose that setting so I'll have to figure out how to do it).

Comment: I ran the scenario on our integration cluster. At the moment there are several jobs like rest-api imports and trigger streams. Now I have on the Channel Page 109 channels. Today morning the channels were 143

Comment: So the error appears to be because a reply is received from the broker after the channel has closed; this should not happen as far as I can tell from the rabbit client code. I think increasing the cache size will solve it (so we don't physically close the channel).

Comment: OK i got it...can i make something on 1.3.0.RELEASE to avoid the exception or must i wait the next update?

Comment: It's not exposed on 1.3.x either - I'll add an answer with a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a reply coming back on a channel that is already closed. When that occurs, the connection is torn down and all users will get that exception. As far as I can tell from the rabbit client code, that shouldn't happen.

Everything should recover though.

Spring AMQP has a channel cache to avoid closing channels and allows them to be reused; increasing the channel cache size (from the default 1), might solve the issue. You seem to be churning a lot of channels.

Spring XD currently doesn't expose the channel cache size as a property. To work around that, put the following file (named `rabbit-bus.xml`) under `xd/config/META-INF/spring-xd/bus`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="rabbitFactory" />
        <property name="addresses" value="${spring.rabbitmq.addresses}" />
        <property name="username" value="${spring.rabbitmq.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${spring.rabbitmq.password}" />
        <property name="virtualHost" value="${spring.rabbitmq.virtual_host}" />
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="${spring.rabbitmq.channelCacheSize:100}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rabbitFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="useSSL" value="${spring.rabbitmq.useSSL:false}" />
        <property name="sslPropertiesLocation" value="${spring.rabbitmq.sslProperties:}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageBus" class="org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus">
        <constructor-arg ref="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="codec"/>
        <property name="defaultAcknowledgeMode" value="#{T(org.springframework.amqp.core.AcknowledgeMode).${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.ackMode}}" />
        <property name="defaultBackOffInitialInterval" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.backOffInitialInterval}" />
        <property name="defaultBackOffMaxInterval" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.backOffMaxInterval}" />
        <property name="defaultBackOffMultiplier" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.backOffMultiplier}" />
        <property name="defaultChannelTransacted" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.transacted}" />
        <property name="defaultConcurrency" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.concurrency}" />
        <property name="defaultDefaultDeliveryMode" value="#{T(org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageDeliveryMode).${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.deliveryMode}}" />
        <property name="defaultDefaultRequeueRejected" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.requeue}" />
        <property name="defaultMaxAttempts" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.maxAttempts}" />
        <property name="defaultMaxConcurrency" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.maxConcurrency}" />
        <property name="defaultPrefetchCount" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.prefetch}" />
        <property name="defaultPrefix" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.prefix}" />
        <property name="defaultReplyHeaderPatterns" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.replyHeaderPatterns}" />
        <property name="defaultRequestHeaderPatterns" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.requestHeaderPatterns}" />
        <property name="defaultTxSize" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.txSize}" />
        <property name="defaultAutoBindDLQ" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.autoBindDLQ}" />
        <property name="defaultRepublishToDLQ" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.republishToDLQ}" />
        <property name="defaultBatchingEnabled" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.batchingEnabled}" />
        <property name="defaultBatchSize" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.batchSize}" />
        <property name="defaultBatchBufferLimit" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.batchBufferLimit}" />
        <property name="defaultBatchTimeout" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.batchTimeout}" />
        <property name="defaultCompress" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.compress}" />
        <property name="compressingPostProcessor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.postprocessor.GZipPostProcessor">
                <property name="level" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.compressionLevel:#{T(java.util.zip.Deflater).BEST_SPEED}}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="decompressingPostProcessor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.postprocessor.DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor">
                <!-- set a map of decompressors here if using other than the default -->
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDurableSubscription" value="${xd.messagebus.rabbit.default.durableSubscription}" />
        <property name="addresses" value="${spring.rabbitmq.addresses:}" />
        <property name="adminAddresses" value="${spring.rabbitmq.adminAddresses:}" />
        <property name="nodes" value="${spring.rabbitmq.nodes:}" />
        <property name="username" value="${spring.rabbitmq.username:}" />
        <property name="password" value="${spring.rabbitmq.password:}" />
        <property name="vhost" value="${spring.rabbitmq.virtual_host:}" />
        <property name="useSSL" value="${spring.rabbitmq.useSSL:false}" />
        <property name="sslPropertiesLocation" value="${spring.rabbitmq.sslProperties:}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This replaces the standard bus configuration (it's a copy except for the connection factory configuration).

It will set the cache to 100 by default, but you can override it in `servers.yml` with

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    channelCacheSize: 200
```

**EDIT**

There is a better work-around, using the bus extension mechanism - simply put he replacement connection factory beans in the bus exension directory...

```
$ cat xd/config/META-INF/spring-xd/bus/ext/cf.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="rabbitFactory" />
        <property name="addresses" value="${spring.rabbitmq.addresses}" />
        <property name="username" value="${spring.rabbitmq.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${spring.rabbitmq.password}" />
        <property name="virtualHost" value="${spring.rabbitmq.virtual_host}" />
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="${spring.rabbitmq.channelCacheSize:100}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any file name ending `.xml` will be found in that directory.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. The workaround is working. Thank you. Can the ressource consumption (f.e. amount of message channel) per module be measured or monitored?

Comment: There's nothing more than what the Rabbit Admin UI provides, I'm afraid. Each XD module will have a long-lived (consumer) channel that is never cached; on the sending side, channels are borrowed for a very brief time from the cache. We don't currently expose the cache statistics, I [opened a JIRA for that](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-581). You shouldn't need a very big cache because publishes are so brief but I would set it large enough such that you don't see channels rapidly appearing and disappearing on the Admin UI.